# Spark slf4j logs not printed on conso

Tags: java, apache-spark, slf4j

I have spark program that uses @Slf4j lombok annotation to print logs but those dont show up in my spark logs. I get this warning when my spark starts

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at \[jar:file:/Users/twisha.saraiya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class\]
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at \[jar:file:/Users/twisha.saraiya/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class\]
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at \[jar:file:/Users/twisha.saraiya/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-reload4j/1.7.35/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.35.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class\]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

I have below dependencies in my pom

```
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mysql.version>8.0.16</mysql.version>
    </properties>

.... skipped some internal dependencies


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

My log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, console

# Console appender configuration
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out

## File appender configuration
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=driver.log
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=1
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=driver-%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern={"level":"%p","timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","thread":"%t", "line":"%L","message":"%m"}%n
```